# In what language these are made

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, desktop-application

I have seen some applications having such a rich layout that a person starts hating desktop applications like traditional c#.I was wondering how to make applications having GUI like this is it possible to make it in c#? [image]

Comment: You may want to blur out your serial key in your screen shot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the programming language. What you need is:

- a UI framework that *allows* rich layouts (in C#, you'd use WPF),
- and, even more important, a *designer*. With "designer", I mean a human, not a tool. If you look at your screenshot, you will notice that the colors of the background image match those of the buttons, that the buttons match the content circle, that the header of the content circle ("Getting Started") matches the header of the window.

So, really, this is not a matter of programming language. What you need is a *design*. Implementing it is the easy part (at least with technologies such as WPF).

Comment: I agree with you.But why dont FORMS support these things and how much I have to struggle to learn WPF as i know c# and had made many desktop applications

Comment: Because WinForms is about 8 years old. Yes, it's possible with WinForms as well, but it's harder, since you don't have the theming/styling capabilities of WPF. In WinForms, you need to override the `Render` method of your custom control and then use basic drawing primitives to paint your control to the screen. Usually, that's a lot more work than using XAML, the declaration language of WPF.

Answer (score 7):

According to the title, this uses WPF, which can be used with C# and/or XAML. It can actually be used with any .NET language.

Comment: ignoring the title might help because I have opened WPF resource center thats why same are for silverlite etc

Comment: Silverlight and WPF are very similar and can create similar user interfaces. The main difference is that Silverlight has fewer apis. It is like a subset of WPF. But really, you can make any type of user interface with any language. WPF and Silverlight are just the latest technologies for .NET and so they are the easiest to use to develop great looking UIs.

Comment: Well are they able to perform all the functionalities as desktop application dose

Comment: WPF is able to when it is run as an executable. When it is run as an XBAP in a browser, it has fewer rights. Silverlight is a web technology, so it always has fewer rights and functionalities, even when run out of browser.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the window title... "Xceed DataGrid for WPF Recource Center". I might be going out on a limb here, but I'm guessing that it was written using WPF and C#.

Comment: hah! your eyes are better than mine... I totally munged the "WPF" into something else.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Only the developers know for sure!</strike> Okay, the window title gives it away

Quick guess, they're using [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), which isn't a language, but part of the .NET Framework (starting with 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Adding some resources here . . .

You have to use WPF for that, and probably with some custom controls.

For WPF have a look here:

1. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)
2. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)
3. [Expression Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/)

For already made controls you can check:

1. [Xceed](http://xceed.com/pages/TopMenu/Products/ProductSearch.aspx?Lang=EN-CA&Category=0617b4dd-af9a-4e34-a1a1-d1129237d614)
2. [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx)
3. [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/)

There are a lot more out there even a lot of free ones. All the above are commercial but i think they have a few free samples.